# MakeHuman Mouth keys

Tags: bones, makehuman, pose-mode

I have a MakeHuman model imported into blender. In the armature, there are bones that control many different parts of the mouth. However, there were no shape keys that predefined the positions of the mouth when pronouncing words. Is there a way for me to create shape keys or something similar by adjusting the positions of the bone and record them along with being able to adjust them from the pose position to the rest position?

This means I can set the mouth poses from a, e, i, o, u and have some in between multiple poses. I'm not asking you to do them for me, I just do not know how to make shape keys with bones.

Comment: You could setup the pose, then apply the armature modifier. This only works once though.